# Find solutions for multivariable mutliplicative group equation

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, octave

I have put the following into wolframalpha.com
$$
    11 \equiv x* \left(y^{119}\right)^{149} \pmod{151}
$$
It is giving me a set of solutions back. Is it just iterating over all the values of x and y, since my group is so small, or is there something else that can be done to find those solutions efficiently? How can I replicate this feature in Octave, or programmatically?

Ideally i'd like to do this sort of thing for a much larger group (512 bit integers)

Comment: over which group are you working? $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_{151}$?

Comment: yes the group is Z_151

Comment: Since $151$ is prime, for each choice of $y$ there is a unique $x$ solving the equation, namely $x = 11(y^{119})^{-149} \pmod{151}$.  Also note that since the group of units $G := (\mathbb{Z}/151\mathbb{Z})^\times$ has order $150$, then $t^{149} = t^{-1}$ for all $t \in G$.  So you should be able to simplify the above formula to $x = 11y^{119}$, so the nonzero solutions are of the form $(x,y) = (11y^{119}, y)$.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Does this still imply that to get all possible non zero solutions, I would need to generate those pairs of (x,y) for all y<151 and then remove the non-zeros, and duplicates, if i wanted to see the unique solution set?

Comment: I just re-read your comment, and I see that you said since 151 was prime, each y would have a unique x. can you comment on the implications if I was using 152 instead of 151?